# Unable to update the column value MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure in MySQL like below

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `UpdateJoin`(
 IN inputSeriesFacilitationId CHAR(36))
BEGIN
DECLARE v_oldCount INT;

START TRANSACTION;

-- Acquire a row-level lock
SELECT ParticipantCount INTO v_oldCount
FROM SeriesFacilitations
WHERE Id = inputSeriesFacilitationId
FOR UPDATE;

-- Check if the row exists
IF (v_oldCount IS NOT NULL) THEN
    -- Update the count
    UPDATE SeriesFacilitations
    SET ParticipantCount = v_oldCount + 1
    WHERE Id = inputSeriesFacilitationId;

    -- Commit the transaction
    COMMIT;
ELSE
    -- Rollback the transaction if the row doesn't exist
    ROLLBACK;
END IF;
END
```

But when I executes this procedure I am getting the following error

> "Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column".

But I am sure that Id is the primary key column of SeriesFacilitations table

Tabel structure is given below
[image]

```
    CREATE TABLE `seriesfacilitations` (
   `Id` char(36) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   `Title` longtext,
   `Description` longtext,
   `SeriesId` char(36) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   `StartTime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
   `EndTime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
   `Status` int NOT NULL,
   `CreatedBy` char(36) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   `CreatedOn` datetime NOT NULL,
   `ParticipantsDataSourceUrl` longtext,
   `ParticipantCount` int NOT NULL,
   `PlayMode` int NOT NULL,
   `LeaderboardStatus` int NOT NULL,
   `LeaderboardProcessingStage` int DEFAULT NULL,
   `Version` int NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
   KEY `IX_SeriesId` (`SeriesId`),
   CONSTRAINT `FK_SeriesFacilitations_Series_SeriesId` FOREIGN KEY (`SeriesId`) REFERENCES `series` (`Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: If you post the DDL of your table we'll know for sure.

Comment: @Filburt added it as image

Comment: add as text from show create table tablename. nb:- should we take your word that the table engine allows row level locks?

Comment: Yes. Added it as text.

Comment: That's not the full error message is it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the full error message is You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column. Cannot use range access on index 'PRIMARY' due to type or collation conversion on field 'Id'

change to

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE `UpdateJoin`(
 IN inputSeriesFacilitationId CHAR(36) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin
)
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/oBSbTIAO